# In docker we can update cpu resources using docker update command without restarting the container but why not in k8s ? Even VPA restarts the pods

Tags: docker, kubernetes

Is there a way in k8s that i can update CPU request and limit of the pod dynamically without restarting the original pod. Since docker is the underlying runtime of k8s and using it i can update container CPU resources at runtime with restarting the container so why k8s doesn't provide this feature ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Do you hear about [VPA](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler) (Vertical Pod Autoscaler)?  It supports [request and limits](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/manage-resources-containers/#requests-and-limits). If the node where a Pod is running has enough of a resource available, it's possible (and allowed) for a container to use more resource than its `request` for that resource specifies. However, a container is not allowed to use more than its resource `limit`.

Comment: Pods are meant to be deleted; the system will very routinely delete and recreate pods (if the underlying image or environment variables change in its deployment, if the node a pod is on fails, ...).  Do you have a specific reason you need the pod to not be deleted, and can you tolerate a pod being deleted outside your control?

Comment: @MikołajGłodziak VPA works by injecting resource constraints at pod creation time, and destroying pods that have the wrong settings so they can be recreated; see [Components of VPA](https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/tree/master/vertical-pod-autoscaler#components-of-vpa) and the linked architecture document.

Comment: [kubernetes/kubernetes#5774](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/5774) appears to be the same question, and there may have been an alpha enhancement in Kubernetes 1.17 to allow this?

Comment: Hi @David Maze ,  i did not see anything related to alpha enhancement that you said. Can you explain ??

Comment: @AnkitNigam, please look [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/enhancements/pull/1883). You can find information about alpha enhancement. At the bottom of the page you have entries from the beginning of April.